# Bitwise Manipulation in C

Tags: c

recently I've come across this problem while trying to learn how bitwise operations work.

```
int evenbits(void) {

// Set all the even bits to 1
// Legal operators: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
// No loops or conditionals!
// "int" type only

}
```

I imagine it wants something like 10101010101 returned. After thinking for a bit (I'm VERY new to bitwise operations), I came up with something like this:

```
int result = 0x01; (since hex seems to be what all the other problems use)
result |= 1 << 2;
result |= 1 << 4;

...


result |= 1 << 30;
```

which would set all evens in a 32-bit binary number to 1.

Buuuut...it's inefficient. And also I'm limited to 8 operations, so I go over quite a bit by doing this.

The problem: I can only use hex values up to 255. And I'm limited to 8 operations. So this solutions just doesn't actually work. So I need some help coming up with a different solution that can fit the criteria.

Comment: Well... what would be the hex value of a full byte with all even bits set?  Why do one bit at a time when you can do them all at once?

Comment: Why do you think it's inefficient? The compiler will see what you're doing and generate the best code.

Comment: Clarified the question a little.

Comment: presumably you are allowed to use the `=` operator. Are you allowed to use the compound assignment operators?  `|=` etc.

Comment: You are expressly forbidden to:
  1. Use any control constructs such as if, do, while, for, switch, etc.
  2. Define or use any macros.
  3. Define any additional functions in this file.
  4. Call any functions.
  5. Use any other operations, such as &&, ||, -, or ?:
  6. Use any form of casting.
  7. Use any data type other than int.  This implies that you
     cannot use arrays, structs, or unions.

Comment: But |= should be okay.

Comment: I don't understand why not to return just the known constant..

Comment: I can only use ints up to 255, and a 32-bit integer would be way greater than 255.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `char` size variable that holds the pattern. Reuse it to create the `int` size variable.

```
unsigned char one = 0x01;
unsigned char c = one;  // c is b00000001
c = (c << 2) | one;     // c is b00000101
c = (c << 2) | one;     // c is b00010101
c = (c << 2) | one;     // c is b01010101

unsigned int result = c;    // result is 0x00000055
result = (result << 8) | c; // result is 0x00005555
result = (result << 8) | c; // result is 0x00555555
result = (result << 8) | c; // result is 0x55555555
```

**Update**

A better approach:

```
int res = 0x01;          // res is b00000001
res = (res << 2) | res;  // res is b00000101
res = (res << 4) | res;  // res is b01010101, which is 0x00000055
res = (res << 8) | res;  // res is 0x00005555
res = (res << 16) | res; // res is 0x55555555
```

Comment: Hold on, I'm a little confused. Wouldn't only shifting for 2, 4, 8, and 16 end you up with something like 00000000000010000000100010101? The answer implies that all evens should be 1.

Comment: He's not allowed to use `=` either, apparently

Comment: @MattMcNabb is `=` an operator or an assignment?

Comment: I mean he's not allowed to use the assignment operator. (Presumably `int res = 0x01;` is OK as it is part of declaration syntax there, and not an operator).

Comment: After being confused out of my mind...I realized why this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Based on the constraints clarified in the comments, the return value which is expected is 0x55555555. Using only bitshifts and ORs, without any assignment or integer greater than 256 we can do something like:

```
.... 
return 0x00000055 | (0x00000055 << 8) | (0x00000055 << 16) | (0x00000055 << 24);
...
```

(Or, in case the "even" has different meaning, every `5` can be replaced by `A`)

Answer (score 1):

```
int evenbits(void)
{
    return 0xAAu << 24 | 0xAAu << 16 | 0xAAu << 8 | 0xAAu;
}
```

6 operators, no variables or assignment. The `u` is to avoid undefined behaviour (`0xAA << 24` causes UB).  Using `|` instead of `+` means that we do not need parentheses. `+` has higher precedence than `<<`, but `|` doesn't.

If the lowest bit is bit `0` then change `0xAAu` to `0x55`.

Comment: Aren't those the odd-numbered bits, and aren't you shifting a 1 into the sign bit of a signed int? I see - does the `u` defeat that?

Comment: @WeatherVane there are different conventions for [numbering bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering). I'm shifting unsigned values.

Comment: I didn't know that. Does it mean we  always have to say what we mean by "bit 0"?

Comment: @WeatherVane that would be a good idea if it's not clear from context

Comment: So what is the point of having two conventions? Are there two meanings for `1`?

Comment: @WeatherVane it wasn't my idea

Comment: Following my last remark, yes there are! `1` and `/1`

Answer (score 0):

```
int evenbits(void) {

    int x = 85;        // x   0101 0101                               ( 8-bits)
    x = (x << 8) | 85;  // x = 0101 0101 0101 0101                     (16-bits)
    x = (x << 8) | 85;  // x = 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101           (24-bits)
    x = (x << 8) | 85;  // x = 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 (32 bits)
    return x;
}
```

Perhaps a little tighter:

```
int evenbits(void) {

    int x = (85 << 8) | 85; // x = 0101 0101 0101 0101                     (16-bits)
    x = (x << 16) | x;      // x = 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 (32-bits)
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Less than 8 operations (32 bit)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int val = 1;
    val = val <<  2 | val;
    val = val <<  4 | val;
    val = val <<  8 | val;
    val = val << 16 | val;
    printf ("Value = %0X\n", val);
    return  0;    
}
```

Since there isn't a `1` bit shifted into the ms bit of a signed integer, it works.

Program output:

```
55555555
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the solution is something along the lines of

```
    return (0x55 | 0x55 << 8 | 0x55 << 16 | 0x55 << 24);
```

or

```
    return ~(0x55 | 0x55 << 8 | 0x55 << 16 | 0x55 << 24);
```

or similar, depending on how bit positions are considered (starting from 0 or 1)